# pip install dotenv error code 1 Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, shell, virtualenv

I am in a virtualenv and trying to run through pip installs. I know the code works because outside the virtualenv this code has worked. I am running on a Windows 10 machine. Using the Git Bash terminal or the regular command prompt (have tried as admin and regular user).
I am trying to run 
`pip install dotenv`
or 
`python -m pip install dotenv` 
and neither of the two work. I get the error saying

> AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader' 
>   During handling of the above exception, another
>   exception occurred:Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with
>   error code 1 in
>   C:\Users\USER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-7bbdcnx2\dotenv\

I have also tried to do things such as `python -m pip install setuptools --upgrade`
un-install setuptools and install it again. restart my computer. and many other things. I'm not too sure what else to try (i've installed *flask* before this and it worked, I also can install other things like *mitmproxy* as an example)
Any ideas? Again, this is a Windows 10 machine and I just want to install **dotenv** for Python (version 3.6.4 if it matters).
Thank you.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

You should install `python-dotenv`

```sh
pip3 install python-dotenv
```

or

```sh
pip install python-dotenv
```

i.e

```
C:\Users\USER>pip3 install python-dotenv
Collecting python-dotenv
  Downloading python_dotenv-0.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: python-dotenv
Successfully installed python-dotenv-0.8.2
```

Refer this [issue](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv/issues/53)

Comment: i had to do this with sudo for trying to install python-dotenv on ubuntu

Comment: thanks that worked.  it is so annoying when people don't use the same name for the package and for the module.  

Answer (score 3):

for me  this error occurred while trying to install **pip install dotenv**

> This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem
> with pip.
> error: metadata-generation-failed
> Encountered error while generating package metadata.

**pip3 install python-dotenv** worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, specify the python I was using worked for me

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip    
python3 -m pip install python-dotenv
```

Or

```
 python -m pip install --upgrade pip    
 python -m pip install python-dotenv
```