# Can't figure out why I can't download dependencies for python discord bot

Tags: python

Recently started trying to learn python and decided a discord bot would be a nice first project after learning the basic syntax. However, when I tried starting my project and installing dotenv, it is telling me
`ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info` .

I have tried looking up the issue as many other people had a similar problem but none of their solutions have worked so far. Some of these include updating pip, updating east_setup, and even reinstalling the newest version of python (3.9). I will also post the full log underneath. Any help would be great! I have been stuck on this for so long and finally got frustrated enough to make a stackoverflow account to ask.

````
Collecting dotenv
  Using cached dotenv-0.0.5.tar.gz (2.4 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\asiantech2.0\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\AsianTech2.0\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-lqyvg56f\\dotenv_4ce8f9751602405a994e3ad1a9e33143\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\AsianTech2.0\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-lqyvg56f\\dotenv_4ce8f9751602405a994e3ad1a9e33143\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\AsianTech2.0\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-6c0x8ni6'
         cwd: C:\Users\AsianTech2.0\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lqyvg56f\dotenv_4ce8f9751602405a994e3ad1a9e33143\
    Complete output (51 lines):
        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
         command: 'c:\users\asiantech2.0\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\AsianTech2.0\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-wheel-ydsv7cug\\distribute_88bad162e5e34d848a7734a6358d0a36\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\AsianTech2.0\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-wheel-ydsv7cug\\distribute_88bad162e5e34d848a7734a6358d0a36\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\AsianTech2.0\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-xa6k7hpy'
             cwd: C:\Users\AsianTech2.0\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-ydsv7cug\distribute_88bad162e5e34d848a7734a6358d0a36\
        Complete output (15 lines):
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
          File "C:\Users\AsianTech2.0\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-ydsv7cug\distribute_88bad162e5e34d848a7734a6358d0a36\setuptools\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
            from setuptools.extension import Extension, Library
          File "C:\Users\AsianTech2.0\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-ydsv7cug\distribute_88bad162e5e34d848a7734a6358d0a36\setuptools\extension.py", line 5, in <module>
            from setuptools.dist import _get_unpatched
          File "C:\Users\AsianTech2.0\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-ydsv7cug\distribute_88bad162e5e34d848a7734a6358d0a36\setuptools\dist.py", line 7, in <module>
            from setuptools.command.install import install
          File "C:\Users\AsianTech2.0\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-ydsv7cug\distribute_88bad162e5e34d848a7734a6358d0a36\setuptools\command\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>      
            from setuptools.command import install_scripts
          File "C:\Users\AsianTech2.0\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-ydsv7cug\distribute_88bad162e5e34d848a7734a6358d0a36\setuptools\command\install_scripts.py", line 3, in <module>
            from pkg_resources import Distribution, PathMetadata, ensure_directory
          File "C:\Users\AsianTech2.0\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-ydsv7cug\distribute_88bad162e5e34d848a7734a6358d0a36\pkg_resources.py", line 1518, in <module>
            register_loader_type(importlib_bootstrap.SourceFileLoader, DefaultProvider)
        AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'
        ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\asiantech2.0\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py", line 126, in fetch_build_egg
        subprocess.check_call(cmd)
      File "c:\users\asiantech2.0\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 373, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['c:\\users\\asiantech2.0\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', 'C:\\Users\\ASIANT~1.0\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp36dip0ns', '--quiet', 'distribute']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\AsianTech2.0\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lqyvg56f\dotenv_4ce8f9751602405a994e3ad1a9e33143\setup.py", line 13, in <module>
        setup(name='dotenv',
      File "c:\users\asiantech2.0\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 152, in setup
        _install_setup_requires(attrs)
      File "c:\users\asiantech2.0\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 147, in _install_setup_requires
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      File "c:\users\asiantech2.0\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 673, in fetch_build_eggs
        resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
      File "c:\users\asiantech2.0\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 764, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
      File "c:\users\asiantech2.0\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1049, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "c:\users\asiantech2.0\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1061, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "c:\users\asiantech2.0\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 732, in fetch_build_egg
        return fetch_build_egg(self, req)
      File "c:\users\asiantech2.0\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py", line 128, in fetch_build_egg
        raise DistutilsError(str(e)) from e
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['c:\\users\\asiantech2.0\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', 'C:\\Users\\ASIANT~1.0\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp36dip0ns', '--quiet', 'distribute']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.```
````

Comment: I think this problem was already solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49328525/pip-install-dotenv-error-code-1-windows-10/49328725

Comment: I tried it and I think it works now in VScode but when I run it in PyCharm it still does not work. Any ideas? I will continue trying in VScode as I think that works fine now though, thank you!